# Delete folders from GCS using Java API

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to delete a folder in GCS with the following code, I need to delete a folder inside a folder with all of it's containing data.

```
Storage storage = CredentialsProvider.getStorageService();
Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list("pdf", 
                Storage.BlobListOption.prefix("parent_folder/folder_to_delete"), 
                Storage.BlobListOption.currentDirectory());

for (Blob blob : blobs.iterateAll()) {
      System.out.println(blob.getName());
      storage.delete(blob.getBlobId());
}
```

This code prints all the folders within the `folder_to_delete` folder but not removing anything. Do we have other approach to delete a folder?

Answer (score 2):

Because folders does not exist, you can't delete a folder.

A folder is a human representation of path separated by /. Remove all the object in the same path (i.e. folder) the folder will disappear.

More detail here on the ["folders"](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders)